# LED-strips, resistance, and voltage drop -- full on layman question

Tags: led-strip

When knowledge and ambition diverge-- ask.

I have a number of LED strip lights on my boat.  The ones I use for long periods eventually die, and the ones that only get intermittent use are still going strong.  I have a lot that still work and even more new strips on rolls that i would like not to waste.

The house voltage is about 14.4V, i suspect this is too high, and i'm not willing to change this.  I have used LM 2596 buck converters on a few strips and i believe that has helped.  Nothing about this is expensive but I am remote, and don't have access to shops to buy this stuff, and I also don't want to bring a whole bunch of circuit boards into the world for no reason.

So first question: Is voltage my problem?

2nd question: Can I use resistors to drop the voltage down, and if so how do i calculate the value?

I understand this is a basic question, I just want to fix problems and learn.  I have limited resources and when i experiment blindly i tend to brake stuff before I start getting results.

Comment: Is it always 14.4V, or do you have 12V batteries and an alternator that brings it up to 14.4V?

Comment: `Is voltage my problem?` ... how can anyone answer such a question without knowing anything about the LEDs? ... `Could voltage be my problem?` is answerable

Comment: Water pumps, engines, alternators, anchor winches and other devices on board may generate noise and peak voltages that can destroy unprotected LEDs. Any electrical system I know of that’s designed for use on a boat is able to withstand far higher peak voltages than 14.4V. I have several consumer devices on board (like my TV) that work at (exactly) 12V and for this purpose I have a DC-DC voltage regulator that brings the house voltage (that may be noisy and up to 14.7V) down to a stable 12V.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this is speculation based on incomplete information ...

Yes, it is possible that overvoltage is your problem. The specification for the LED strips may give the acceptable range.

A series resistor will only work if the load is constant. If LED banks switch independently, or are dimmable, then the load won't be constant.

An LDO regulator is a good solution.

A simpler solution would be a few diodes in series. Probably 3 silicon diodes. I once used a diode to drop a 6V battery voltage down to supply TTL (5V).

You may also have voltage spikes on your 14.4V, put some caps after the diodes.

Answer (score 0):

The 12V dumb led stripes with 5050 chips are designed for 12V nominal car systems and have resistors for about 16 or 17mA per color per segment when powered at 12V. At 14.4V they are closer to the 20mA nominal max of the leds. Or higher which affects the average life.. Depending on the source you may also have sub par chips. Any coating would cause heat issues and can affect the life of the led.

Using buck regulators to get a nice 12V is a good way to ensure they last longer. Even 1 or 2 mA less due to a lower voltage would help the leds live longer as heat would decrease. I'd go down more than 12V, to 11 or 10.5 depending on the brightness you need.

Resistors are not ideal depending on the length of your led strips as the power they waste in heat would add up. At 1 amp and a 3 volt drop from 14.4V, you are looking at 3V * 1A = 3 Watts to dissipate. A 5M rgb roll is much higher than 1A.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using 12V, yes, 14V is enough to make them wear out faster than normal. And you are also wasting much more energy.
My advise is to keep using your LM 2596 buck converters. One for each LED strip.
Adjust the voltage to 11V or 11.5V and they will last longer than your boat. ;) (If you have an adjustable converter)